# Main method not found in class/illegal start of expression

Tags: java, class, methods, program-entry-point

I am new to all of this and really only have a basic understanding of coding in general.

I am actually trying to use a java code that was published in ChemMedChem (dx.doi.org/10.1002/cmdc.200900317 in the supporting information)

i have all the appropriate programs/jar files they use (from ChemAxon)

i am able to copy the code and compile it to a class file with no issues:

```
javac -classpath C:\jarfolder\MarvinBeans-plugin.jar;C:\jarfolder\MarvinBeans.jar; MQN.java
```

though i do get:

```
Note: MQN.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Then when it try to run the class file (the input file is supposed to a virtual chemical input as a smiles code):

```
java -classpath C:\jarfolder\MarvinBeans-plugin.jar;C:\jarfolder\MarvinBeans.jar; MQN test.smiles
```

i get:

```
Error: Main method not found in class MQN, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
```

I tried to enclose the code in

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
```

however i then get error:

```
>MQN.java:10: error: illegal start of expression
public String calculateMQN(Molecule m) {
^
>MQN.java:10: error: ';' expected
public String calculateMQN(Molecule m) {
                          ^
>MQN.java:10: error: ';' expected
public String calculateMQN(Molecule m) {
                                     ^
>MQN.java:255: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
4 errors
```

below you will find the code that i used (before adding public static void main(String[] args)), any help would be much appreciated

Thanks!

Java Code:

```
    import chemaxon.calculations.TopologyAnalyser; 
    import chemaxon.marvin.calculations.HBDAPlugin; 
    import chemaxon.struc.MolAtom; 
    import chemaxon.struc.MolBond; 
    import chemaxon.struc.Molecule;
    public class MQN { 
    TopologyAnalyser ta = new TopologyAnalyser(); 
    HBDAPlugin hbda = new HBDAPlugin(); 
    public String calculateMQN(Molecule m) { 
        if (!m.dearomatize()) { 
            System.out.println("DEAROMATIZE ERROR"); 
        } 
        ta.setMolecule(m); 
        //Classic descriptors 
        try { 
            hbda.setMolecule(m); 
            hbda.run(); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.err.println("HBDA ERROR"); 
        } 
        int hbd = hbda.getDonorAtomCount(); 
        int hbdm = hbda.getDonorCount(); 
        int hba = hbda.getAcceptorAtomCount();
        int hbam = hbda.getAcceptorCount(); 
        /*Reymond style Rot bond count*/
        int rbc = ta.rotatableBondCount(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < m.getBondCount(); i++) { 
            if (m.getBond(i).getType() == 3) { 
                rbc--; 
            } 
        } 
        if (rbc < 0) { 
            rbc = 0; 
        } 
        //Ring properties / ring sizes count 
        int r3 = 0, r4 = 0, r5 = 0, r6 = 0, r7 = 0, r8 = 0, r9 = 0, rg10 = 0; 
        int[][] sssr = m.getSSSR(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < sssr.length; i++) { 
            switch (sssr[i].length) { 
                case 3: 
                    r3++; 
                    break; 
                case 4: 
                    r4++; 
                    break; 
                case 5: 
                    r5++; 
                    break; 
                case 6: 
                    r6++; 
                    break; 
                case 7: 
                    r7++; 
                    break; 
                case 8: 
                    r8++; 
                    break; 
                case 9: 
                    r9++; 
                    break; 
                default: 
                    rg10++; 
                    break; 
            } 
        } 
        //Atom properties 
        int c = 0, f = 0, cl = 0, br = 0, I = 0, thac = 0, asv = 0, adv = 0, atv = 0, aqv = 0, 
                cdv = 0, ctv = 0, cqv = 0, p = 0, s = 0, posc = 0, negc = 0, 
                afrc = 0, cn = 0, an = 0, co = 0, ao = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < m.getAtomCount(); i++) { 
            MolAtom at = m.getAtom(i); 
            boolean isRingAt = ta.isRingAtom(i);
            if (at.getAtno() != 1) { 
                thac++; 
            } 
            //element counts 
            switch (at.getAtno()) { 
                case 1: 
                case 2: 
                case 3: 
                case 4: 
                case 5: 
                    break; 
                case 6: 
                    c++; 
                    break; 
                case 7: 
                    if (isRingAt) { 
                        cn++; 
                    } else { 
                        an++; 
                    } 
                    break; 
                case 8: 
                    if (isRingAt) { 
                        co++; 
                    } else { 
                        ao++; 
                    } 
                    break; 
                case 15: 
                    p++; 
                    break; 
                case 16: 
                    s++; 
                    break; 
                case 9: 
                    f++; 
                    break; 
                case 17: 
                    cl++; 
                    break; 
                case 35: 
                    br++; 
                    break; 
                case 53: 
                    I++; 
                    break; 
            } 
            //valency count 
            switch (at.getBondCount()) {
                case 0: 
                    System.out.println("ATOM WITH NO BONDS"); 
                    break; 
                case 1: 
                    asv++; //single valent can only be acyclic 
                    break; 
                case 2: 
                    if (isRingAt) { 
                        cdv++; 
                    } else { 
                        adv++; 
                    } 
                    break; 
                case 3: 
                    if (isRingAt) { 
                        ctv++; 
                    } else { 
                        atv++; 
                    } 
                    break; 
                case 4: 
                    if (isRingAt) { 
                        cqv++; 
                    } else { 
                        aqv++; 
                    } 
                    break; 
            } 
            if (ta.ringCountOfAtom(i) > 1) { 
                afrc++; 
            } 
        } 
        //Bond properties 
        int csb = 0, cdb = 0, ctb = 0, asb = 0, adb = 0, atb = 0, bfrc = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < m.getBondCount(); i++) { 
            MolBond bd = m.getBond(i); 
            if (ta.isRingBond(i)) { 
                switch (bd.getType()) { 
                    case 1: 
                        csb++; 
                        break; 
                    case 2: 
                        cdb++; 
                        break; 
                    case 3: 
                        ctb++; 
                        break; 
                    default: 
                        System.out.println("UNKNOWN CYCLIC BOND TYPE " + bd.getType()); 
                        break; 
                }
            } else { 
                switch (bd.getType()) { 
                    case 1: 
                        asb++; 
                        break; 
                    case 2: 
                        adb++; 
                        break; 
                    case 3: 
                        atb++; 
                        break; 
                    default: 
                        System.out.println("UNKNOWN ACYCLIC BOND TYPE " + bd.getType()); 
                        break; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        //bond's fused ring count 
        int[][] sssre = m.getSSSRBonds(); 
        int[] brc = new int[m.getBondCount()]; 
        for (int j = 0; j < sssre.length; j++) { 
            for (int k = 0; k < sssre[j].length; k++) { 
                brc[sssre[j][k]]++; 
            } 
        } 
        for (int j = 0; j < brc.length; j++) { 
            if (brc[j] > 1) { //if bond's ring count > 1 
                bfrc++; //increase fused ring bonds count 
            } 
        } 
        for (int i = 0; i < m.getAtomCount(); i++) { 
            int crg = m.getAtom(i).getCharge(); 
            if (crg > 0) { 
                posc += crg; 
            } 
            if (crg < 0) { 
                negc += Math.abs(crg); 
            } 
        } 
        return  //CLASSIC PROPERTIES 
                hbd + ";" //hydrogen bond donor atom count 1 
                + hbdm + ";" //HBD with multivalency 2 
                + hba + ";" //hydrogen bond acceptor atom count 3 
                + hbam + ";" //HBA with multivalency 4 
                + rbc + ";" //rotatable bond count 5 
                //RING PROPERTIES 
                + r3 + ";" + r4 + ";" + r5 + ";" + r6 + ";" + r7 + ";" + r8 + ";" + r9 + ";" + rg10 + ";"
    //RingSize Counts 6-13 
                //ATOM PROPERTIES
                + thac + ";"//total heavy atom count (= everything else than H D T) 14 
                + c + ";" //carbon count 15 
                + p + ";"//phosphorus 16 
                + s + ";"//sulfur atom count 17 
                + f + ";" //fluor atom count 18 
                + cl + ";" //chlorine atom count 19
                + br + ";" //bromine atom count 20 
                + I + ";" //iodine atom count 21 
                + cn + ";" //cyclic nitrogen count 22 
                + an + ";" //acyclic nitrogen count 23 
                + co + ";" //cyclic oxygen count 24
                + ao + ";" //acyclic oxygen count 25 
                + asv + ";"//acyclic single valent atom count 26 
                + adv + ";"//acyclic double valent atom count 27 
                + atv + ";"//acyclic triple valent atom count 28 
                + aqv + ";"//acyclic quart valent atom count 29 
                + cdv + ";"//cyclic double valent atom count 30 
                + ctv + ";"//cyclic triple valent atom count 31 
                + cqv + ";"//cyclic quart valent atom count 32 
                + afrc + ";"//atoms-in-fused-ring count 33 
                + posc + ";" // Positive charges 34
                + negc + ";" // Negative charges 35
                //BOND PROPERTIES 
                + csb + ";"//cyclic single bonds 36
                + cdb + ";"//cyclic double bonds 37
                + ctb + ";"//cyclic triple bonds 38
                + asb + ";"//acyclic singe bonds 39
                + adb + ";"//acyclic double bonds 40 
                + atb + ";"//acyclic triple bonds 41 
                + bfrc + ";"//bonds-in-fused-ring count 42 
                + m.toFormat("smiles:q");//END 43 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can not run this jar file as stand-alone application, you can use it only as library.

Comment: There's a closing bracket } missing at the end of the file.

Comment: um, maybe im just horribly lost but i thought i was creating and running a class file not a jar file?

Comment: I do understand that the program requires an input file as well which is why i type "MQN test.smiles"
where test.smiles is my input file that the program is supposed to analyze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add main like this

```
...............................
...............................

public class MQN {

    TopologyAnalyser ta = new TopologyAnalyser();
    HBDAPlugin hbda = new HBDAPlugin();

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // This is where the execution of the program will begin

    }

    public String calculateMQN(Molecule m) {
        if (!m.dearomatize()) {
            System.out.println("DEAROMATIZE ERROR");
    .............
    ..............
```

Post a comment here if you still get compiler errors

Comment: Thanks, no longer getting the error
But im also not getting any output, there is most likely something else big im not getting about this code, unfortunately the original author of the code has yet to get back to me.

Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 3):

Your class indeed does not contain `main` method that must follow this signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

This method is an entry point to your program that should invoke other methods, create objects etc.

Comment: When i add that 
ie:
`import chemaxon.calculations.TopologyAnalyser;
import chemaxon.marvin.calculations.HBDAPlugin;
import chemaxon.struc.MolAtom; 
import chemaxon.struc.MolBond; 
import chemaxon.struc.Molecule;
class MQN { 
    TopologyAnalyser ta = new TopologyAnalyser(); 
    HBDAPlugin hbda = new HBDAPlugin();
    public static void main(String[] args){
    public String calculateMQN(Molecule m) { `

i get the second error i mentioned above

Comment: @kask382 The answer is correct. But you can't put one method inside another. `main` method should close before declaring `calculateMQN(){}`.

Comment: @user000001 so which part exactly do i need to enclose in the main method? when i put it after class MQN and close it before public String when i try to compile i get error cannot find the symbols ta, hbda etc.

Comment: @kask382 I added an example as a separate answer